# thread.is_alive() or thread.isAlive() not working

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following thread

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=editing, args=(values['_CHECK_'], files, directory, window, progress_bar,), daemon=True).start()
```

and want to check whether the thread is still running or not.

```
if not thread.is_alive()
    pass
```

or

```
if not thread.isAlive():
    pass
```

are both not working. Why?

Exception:

```
File "Progress.py", line 101, in progress
    if not thread.isAlive():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isAlive'
```

Comment: Well it seems that it thinks thread = none, which none doesn't have .isAlive()

Answer (score 4):

This is because [`start()` just Start the thread’s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) activity and return `None`. You probably indented to write

```
>>> thread = threading.Thread(target=editing, args=(values['_CHECK_'], files, directory, window, progress_bar,), daemon=True)
>>> thread.start() # start the thread
>>> is_alive = thread.is_alive()
>>> print(is_alive)
```

Comment: How do I wait till the thread is finished to execute other stuff? Like "if thread is done do x". thread.join() is not working and is_alive() in this constellation either.

Comment: `thread.join()` is what you call to wait until the thread is finished; it will not return until the thread has exited.